# substring of a column

Tags: sql, teradata

How can I select all records that have `column1` where the 6th and 7th digit represent *35* for example *13129350250* ?

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Comment: Is the column numeric or char?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tablename
where substr(column1, 6, 2) = '35'
```

You can use `substr` to do that assuming all the values in column1 have fixed length.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the 6th and 7th digits you can also use a simple

```
WHERE col LIKE '_____35%'
```

This might be a bit more efficient than

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(col FROM 6 FOR 2) = '35'
```